# What can I use to rigidly hang a lot of flat/paper artwork on a wall?

Tags: hanging, diy-vs-pro

I have dozens of pieces of unframed artwork. I would like to hang them on the wall, in a way that is somewhat easy to rearrange. I'd like them to line up horizontally, and to be against the wall so they don't swing/flap as much when the room's ceiling fan is on.

I have in mind to simply buy a long piece of wood and glue a few dozen tiny clothes pins to it. I'm hoping there is some better / nicer / easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try painting it with a magnetic paint and use those strong small earth magnetics to hold the art up. The magnetic wall paint can be top-coated with a single coat of whatever colour you want.

There are a number of paints from different manufactures to choose from, some with better reviews than others. It seems multiple coats are needed, but other people report success. Strong magnets are a must.

I have not used this myself, but I have seen it used in a number of design magazines, etc.

Comment: That sample product has a 1.3/5 star rating...

Comment: I have updated the answer. It seems that product link vanished - weird

Answer (score 0):

Ikea sells a curtain wire with clips that works well to hang artwork on.  Use weights at the bottom of the artwork to keep it steady.  Or if all the pieces are the same size, use a second wire at the bottom. http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/60075295/

Comment: I actually bought these, but was unhappily surprised at the size. The posts actually hold the wire about three inches out from the wall. I was hoping it would be more like half an inch.

Answer (score 0):

Take inspiration from what professional art galleries use - they often have a slot in the wall that little hooks slide into.  These hooks are connected with thin wire with hooks at the end for hanging the art work.

But you don't want to make a slot in your wall - too messy and too much work.  What I had planned on doing at one time was to fasten a small piece of wood, say 1"x2" to the wall.  Hammer small nails into the top at regular intervals.  Paint all of this (wood and nails) the wall colour, so it blends in.  Buy some fishing line and make a loop at the top to go over the nail and then tie a hook at the other end.

This solution is almost invisible, is not limited to light weight art pieces, and (very important!) is cheap and easy!  As a bonus, it will only leave a couple of small holes in the wall if you screw the 1x2 strapping into the studs.